# Behave like <ul><ol>

Tags: html, css

Just want to ask if its possible for a normal sentence with a number beside it behave like a `<ul><ol>` without even using `<ul><ol>`?

Below is the sample code:

```
<td>6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel est
tortor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ut sem neque. Suspendisse
vulputate massa nec odio laoreet dignissim. </td>
```

The Below hows it supposed to be:

[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You mean you're looking for css style that will make some other tag behave like a list?

Comment: What do you mean by "behave"? Automatic numbering?

Comment: You'll have to use some sort of tag to make the text show like that. Is there any reason why you're not using the `<ul> <ol>` tags?

Comment: if it needs numbers, it probably IS an ordered list, why the td? or is that tabular data?

Comment: What @corroded said. I think you need to explain a bit more before this can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but you would need extra markup, and you would have to number items manually. But why would you want that?

For example (sorry, with inline css :)):

```
<td style="padding-left:20px;position:relative;">
   <span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;">1.</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel est tortor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ut sem neque. Suspendisse vulputate massa nec odio laoreet dignissim.
</td>
```

It could be done with pure css.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use the right markup to indicate the right structure of your content. If you cannot do it, you can alternatively apply `list-style` and other `<ol>` CSSes to `<td>`s. The hard coded numbers however should be wrapped in `<span>` and set to `display: none` to avoid repletion.